# Spreading time series data in R by trial

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy

I have a poorly formatted time series dataset in which a single column contains **all** time series consecutively, and another column contains the trial number.

Example:

| Trial | Fx |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7.9 |
| 1 | 8.0 |
| 1 | 8.1 |
| 1 | 8.2 |
| 2 | 6.5 |
| 2 | 6.6 |
| 2 | 6.7 |
| 2 | 6.8 |

The ultimate goal is to apply signal::filtfilt() to each time series; however, each time series must be filtered separately for this to work appropriately.

I attempted group_by() prior to `filtfilt()` which resulted in an error. Therefore, I'd like to spread the time series (Fx) into multiple columns by trial so I can filter each column separately, something like this:

| Fx_1 | Fx_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 7.9 | 6.5 |
| 8.0 | 6.6 |
| 8.1 | 6.7 |
| 8.2 | 6.8 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pivot_wider` from `tidyverse` to accomplish this. I added an index using `group_by` and `row_number`. Then, I remove this column after pivoting wider.

```
library(tidyverse)
  
df %>%
  group_by(Trial) %>% 
  mutate(grouped_id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Trial,
              values_from = Fx,
              names_prefix = "Fx_") %>%
  select(-grouped_id)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
   Fx_1  Fx_2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1   7.9   6.5
2   8     6.6
3   8.1   6.7
4   8.2   6.8
```

**Data**

```
df <-
  structure(list(
    Trial = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
    Fx = c(7.9, 8, 8.1, 8.2, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-8L))
```